# Finding a smaller string within a larger string

Tags: c++

The Instructions are: Your program receives from user two strings of symbols: first long one and then short one. Then your program returns all positions in long string where short string occures as a substring.
For example: long string is "aabcccbabc" and short one is "abc". Short string can be seen twice in the long string "aabcccbabc" in positions 1 and 7 (enumeration of positions in string starts as always from 0). Position of the substring is the position of its first symbol in the whole string. You are not allowed to use any built-in tools such as strlen().
 I can't get it to output the number of occurences, nor the number of positions. Please Help! I feel like I have tried everything!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int NUM_MTCH, POSS1, POSS2, LENS1, LENS2 ;
NUM_MTCH=0;    //NUM_MTCH= THE NUMBER OF MATCHES
POSS1=0;       //POSITION OF PATTERM IN STRING2
POSS2=0;       //POSITION OF PATTERN IN STRING1
LENS1=0;       //LENGTH OF FIRST STRING
LENS2=0;       //LENGTH OF SECOND STRING
bool SUCCESS(true);
string S1, S2;
do
{
    cout<< "Enter First String: ";
    cin>> S1;
    for (POSS1=0; S1[POSS1] != '\0'; POSS1++)
    {
        LENS1++;
    }
    cout<< "Enter Second String: ";
    cin>>S2;
    for (POSS2=0; S2[POSS2] != '\0'; POSS2++)
    {
        LENS2++;
    }

}
while(LENS2>LENS1);

while (S1[POSS1] != '\0')
{
for(POSS1=0; S1[POSS2+POSS1]==S2[POSS2]; POSS2++)
{
    if (S1[POSS1+POSS2] == S2[POSS2])
    {
        SUCCESS==true;
    }
}
}

while (S1[POSS1]!= '\0')
{
if (S1[LENS2]==S2[POSS2])
{
    NUM_MTCH++;
    if(NUM_MTCH != 0)
    {
        cout<<"POSITIONS: "<<POSS1;
        cout<<"NUMBER OF OCCURENCES: "<<NUM_MTCH;
    }
}
}
POSS1++; 
if (NUM_MTCH==0)
{
cout<<"NOTHING";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it output?  What have you tried to do to debug this?

Comment: Can you describe your attempt? It's hard to tell your attempt from the code written for you in the file.

Comment: a `std::string` is not NUL terminated, so your check for `\0` won't work

Comment: Right now it only outputs "NOTHING" after I put in the two strings.

Comment: When I ran the program, I inserted: abghab (1st string); then I inserted ab (2nd string). After that I receive the message : NOTHING

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem using [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).  `find()` will search a string for the first occurrence of the supplied string and point to the position it finds it at, If nothing is found it returns `std::string::npos`.  You can keep calling `find()` from the last position found until no more sub-strings are found

```
std::string mainString = "aabcccbabc";
std::string subString = "abc";

std::vector<size_t> positions;
std::size_t index = 0;

// find sub-string and add positrion to vector.  If no string found end the loop
while((index = mainString.find(subString, index)) != std::string::npos)
{
    positions.push_back(index);
    ++index;  // increment index to search for next string
}

for (auto e : positions)
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
```

The output of this is

```
1
7
```

**Edit:**

Since you have a lousy instructor and you are not allowed to use actual C++ you can you the following function to find if the sub-string exist:

```
bool stringcmp(const char* sub, const char* main)
{
    while(*sub && (*sub==*main))
        sub++,main++;
    return *sub == '\0'; // if we didn't reach the end of sub then its false
}
```

And your main program would look like:

```
char* mainString = "aabcccbabc";
char* subString = "abc";
char* crwaler = mainString;

int positions[100];  // assuming there wont be more than 100 occurrences You might want to do something different
int index = 0;
int occurrences = 0;

// go untill the end of the string
while(*crwaler != '\0')
{
    if (stringcmp(subString, crwaler) == true)
    {
        positions[occurrences] = crwaler - mainString;
        occurrences++;
    }
    crwaler++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < occurrences; i++)
    std::cout <<positions[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: I wanted to use this exactly, but my professor said that he did not want us to use any built-in tools, he wants us to use all the loops and drag out the code.

Comment: @dfg221 But your teacher uses `std::string`, which is a "built in tool".  The purpose of using `std::string` **is** to use the "built-in tools" that this class provides, i.e. the public interface.  What a weird requirement.  Sounds like "here's the washing machine, but don't start it -- just fill it with water and wash by hand".

Comment: @dfg221 What class are you taking?  C++ Programing 201: (C++)--?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I felt the exact same way. He didn't even know what find() meant. But he assumed it was a built in tool and told me not to use it. I'm taking CompSci 127.

Comment: @dfg221 I feel sorry for you.  That teacher doesn't know C++, else they would know that std::string is a (template) class that has member functions.

Comment: @dfg221 So basically you are taking a C++ course without the standard template library.  That's BS.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yup, basically I'm going to fail my class because i'm not allowed to use "built-in tools"...oh well I've asked everyone and no one knows.

Comment: @dfg221 And the ironic thing is that you won't find a C++ job if you didn't know how to use the "built in tools".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie EXACTLY. I understand that it's a beginner's class, but if the program does what you want it to do...does it matter what you want the source file to say?

Comment: Upvoting because you're not using any more tools than what is already a member on `std::string`, which OP is allowed to use already.

Comment: @dfg221 The assignment is unfair.  You are not supposed to use "built-in tools", but there is no standard way to know how many characters there are in the string without calling `string::size()`.  Is that considered a built-in tool (calling size())?  As others stated, you cannot rely on the string having a null character at the end so you have no choice but to either call `size()`, or the roundabout way by calling `c_str()` and get the length of the `const char *` that's returned to you by using the loop until you get to the null.  Either way, you're using a "built-in" function.

Comment: @dfg221 I did an edit and it should help you out more.  It is a shame your instructor is doing you such a disservice.

Comment: @NathanOliver He told us the program is too simple (Theres "no need") to use pointers.

Comment: @dfg221 But that doesn't disqualify what I stated.  You **can't** get the number of characters in your input string using a loop on the string.  You must call `size()` or `c_str()` and a counting loop.  I think your professor is looking at the algorithmic side of the fence, and not the impossible requirements he/she imposed on you.  They didn't really think through the `no strlen()` requirement very well.

Comment: @dfg221 Honestly I don't know what he is trying to get at then.  I wish you luck in your class.  I don't think it's going to do you any good.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie He honestly told me, that I have to use a loop to calculate the size of the string. I give up, I don't know what he wants, the program does not function at all and that's what I'm going to give him.

Comment: @NathanOliver I really appreciate all your tries, for real thanks.

Comment: @dfg221 If a loop is all you can use, then the **only** way to do that is here.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfce2c382a52a5d3  If you can't use `c_str()`, then your assignment is impossible to complete, unless you change from `std::string` to raw char arrays.

Comment: @dfg221 If you now take the small sample of how to get the length, plus combine it with the other answers given, you may be able to put together something that works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great deal wrong with this code.

1. a `std::string` does not terminate in a `\0`
2. Your formatting in all CAPS is hard to read
3. You have loops floating everywhere

The basic O(n*m) algorithm (n is length of string 1, m is length of string 2) to do this is as follows:

- For each char in string 1 (the long string)

  - See if this character begins a substring in string 1 that matches string 2 (the short string)

Some short code:

```
size_t matches = 0;
std::string s1 = "aabcccbabc";
std::string s2 = "abc";
for(size_t i=0; i < (s1.size()-s2.size()+1); ++i)
{
    if(s1.substr(i,s2.size()) == s2)
    {
        std::cout << "Found match at index " << i << " in 1st string\n";
        ++matches;
    }
}

std::cout << "Found " << matches << " match(es)" << std::endl;
```

Output:

> Found match at index 1 in 1st string
> Found match at index 7 in 1st string
> Found 2 match(es)

In terms of "built-in tools", you're already using `std::string`, so I restricted myself to only use the really basic functionality like `substr` for getting a substring and `size()` for getting length.

Of course you could do this even easier using other functionality (See NathanOliver's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30271321/27678)), `<algorithm>` or Boost

#### Edit

You can replace the check for `substr` with another loop. That is, this:

```
if(s1.substr(i,s2.size()) == s2)
{
    std::cout << "Found match at index " << i << " in 1st string\n";
    ++matches;
}
```

Becomes:

```
bool match = true;
for(size_t j=0;j<s2.size();++j)
{
    if (s1[i+j] != s2[j])
    {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (match)
{
    std::cout << "Found match at index " << i << " in 1st string\n";
    ++matches;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll change it from all CAPS. I really appreciate it. Can I substitute    substr for something else? He counts that a built in tool.

Answer (score 0):

well, I just made some changes to your code and it works fine now, as you don't want to use built in functions as std::string::size() or std::string::substr()

but first keep in mind: 
 1- a std::string is not NUL terminated, so your check for \0 won't work, as   said above.
 2- Your formatting in all CAPS is hard to read as @andyG said.

Here's the code

```
    #include <iostream>  
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      int NUM_MTCH, POSS1, POSS2, LENS1, LENS2;
      NUM_MTCH = 0;    //NUM_MTCH= THE NUMBER OF MATCHES
      POSS1 = 0;       //POSITION OF PATTERM IN STRING2
      POSS2 = 0;       //POSITION OF PATTERN IN STRING1
      LENS1 = 0;       //LENGTH OF FIRST STRING
      LENS2 = 0;       //LENGTH OF SECOND STRING
      bool SUCCESS(false);
      string S1, S2;

      cout << "Enter First String: ";
      cin >> S1;
      S1 += "\0"; 
      for (POSS1 = 0; S1[POSS1] != '\0'; POSS1++)
      {
         LENS1++;
      }

      cout << "Enter Second String: ";
      cin >> S2;
      S2 += "\0";
      for (POSS2 = 0; S2[POSS2] != '\0'; POSS2++)
      {
        LENS2++;
      }


      for (POSS1 = 0; POSS1 < (LENS1 - LENS2 + 1); POSS1++)
      {
          if (S1[POSS1] == S2[0])
          {
             POSS1++;
             for (int j = 1; j < LENS2; j++){
                if (S1[POSS1] == S2[j]){
                   SUCCESS = true;
                   POSS1++;
                }
                else{
                   SUCCESS = false;
                } 
            }
            if (SUCCESS){
                cout << "at position" << POSS1 - LENS2 << endl;
                NUM_MTCH++;
            }
            POSS1--;

        }
    }



if (NUM_MTCH == 0)
{
    cout << "NOTHING";
}
else{
    cout <<"number of matches: "<< NUM_MTCH << endl;
}



return 0;
```

}